# How can I calculate PER, collisions and channel efficiency using scapy?

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers, collision

How can I  find packet error rate, Channel efficiency and collisions using scapy and python in wifi traffic. 
I have to do this by data from pcap file.
this is how I have opened the pcap file:

```
 file=rdpcap("file1.cap")
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about PER,

there is a bit in the package that treats this.
you can reach to it by using:

```
FCfield & 0x8
```

Here is an example code (you need to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`) :

```
def foo(self):
    number_of_pkts = len(self.pcap_file)
    retransmission_pkts = 0

for pkt in self.pcap_file:
    # cecking if the retransmission flag is on
    if (pkt[Dot11].FCfield & 0x8) != 0:
        retransmission_pkts += 1

ans = (retransmission_pkts / number_of_pkts)*100
ans = float("%.2f" % ans)
labels = ['Standard packets', 'Retransmitted packets']
sizes = [100.0 - ans,ans]


colors = ['g', 'r']

# Make a pie graph
plt.clf()
plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(8, 6))
plt.axes(aspect=1)
plt.suptitle('Retransmitted packet', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 13})
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%.2f%%', startangle=60, colors=colors, pctdistance=0.7, labeldistance=1.2)

plt.show()
```